# How can I capture the return value of shutil.copy() in Python ( on DOS )?

Tags: python, exception, logging

I am trying to record the success or failure of a number of copy commands, into a log file. I'm using `shutil.copy()` - e.g.

```
str_list.append(getbitmapsfrom) 
game.bigbitmap = "i doubt this is there.bmp"
str_list.append(game.bigbitmap)
source = '\\'.join(str_list)
shutil.copy(source, newbigbmpname)
```

I forced one of the copy commands in my script to fail, and it generated the error:

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'X:\PJ_public\PJ_Services\BSkyB-PlayJam\Content\P_NewPortal2009\1.0.0\pframes\i doubt this is is there.bmp'`

This is great, but can I capture `"Errno 2 No such file or directory"` and write it to a log file? Does `shutil.copy()` return an integer value? - I don't see this described in the Python docs.

I guess also I want to be able to capture the return value, so that the script doesn't bomb out on a copy failure - I'm trying to make it continue regardless of errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll want to look at the [exceptions section](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions) of the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html).  In the case of shutil.copy() not finding one of the arguments, an IOError exception will be raised.  You can get the message from the exception instance.

```
try:
    shutil.copy(src, dest)
except IOError, e:
    print "Unable to copy file. %s" % e
```

Comment: I think `e` meant to be `IOError as e` where `as` replaces `,`

Answer (score 4):

You will rarely see C-like return codes in Python, errors are signalled by exceptions instead.

The correct way of logging result is:

```
try:
    shutil.copy(src, dest)
except EnvironmentError:
    print "Error happened"
else:
    print "OK"
```

Comment: many thanks, Alex and Jamessan - I have just tried out the exceptions and this works a treat.

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    shutil.copy(archivo, dirs)
except EnvironmentError:
    print "Error en el copiado"
    escritura = "no se pudo copiar %s a %s \n" % (archivo, dirs)
else:
    print "Copiado con exito"
    escritura = "%s --> %s \n" % (archivo, dirs)
finally:
    log = open("/tmp/errorcreararboldats.log", "a")
    log.write(escritura)
    log.close()
```